# Docker Nginx-Proxy TLS 1.2

Tags: docker, nginx, proxy, tls1.2, jwilder-nginx-proxy

We are currently using docker environment to run our containers. Front of containers we use Nginx-proxy (https://github.com/nginx-proxy/nginx-proxy) and https://github.com/nginx-proxy/docker-letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion to automate HTTPS connections via Let's Encrypt.

Our issue is now that we want to provide TLS 1.2 sertificate to spesific domains. Thats because our customer has some arduino modems to sending data to the server. Arduino modem ip-stacks support onlyt 1.2 tls and now we are running TLS 1.3

Is there any ways to configure TLS 1.2 for lets encrypt generation via Nginx-proxy.

Comment: Just to be said, when some time ago I worked on adding TLS 1.3 support on one on my servers, thing that surprises me is that TLS 1.3 didn't worked until I enable it on all the virtual hosts. I wasn't able to enable it individually only for several virtual hosts. Didn't digger deeper into it.

Comment: With docker + nginx proxy?

Comment: No, without the docker, just with nginx (more precisely, openresty), but I don't think there is any difference, it is nginx who handles the TLS.

Comment: I suggest to ask this question on ServerFault